# Loading APL script from GNU APL session

Tags: apl, gnu-apl

In GNU APL, is there a way to load an APL script (text file) from a running APL session?

Comment: similar to the `-f` option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot add a comment because I keep getting " This action requires 50 reputation."

**Short answer:**

Make the first 2 characters of your script: #!

**Long answer:**

See Chapter 3.1.6 of [Helpful-Features-for-Scripting](http://www.gnu.org/software/apl/apl.html#Helpful-Features-for-Scripting)

Answer (score 1):

In immediate execution you can load the script with commands )LOAD or )COPY.

If an APL program is being executed then e.g. ⍎')COPY filename' can be used.

Comment: When I use `)LOAD` or `)COPY` I get an error message saying that the file "does not have the format of a GNU APL .xml or .apl file".

Comment: I created the script with a normal text editor. What I want is the ability to edit APL code in a plain (UTF-8) text file.